# How can I share a ByteToMessageDecoder?

Tags: java, netty

I have a decoder class that extends [ByteToMessageDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html) that's also marked as shareable via the [ChannelHandler.Sharable](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.Sharable.html) annotation. However I encounter a runtime error with the following [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/PavanChohan/04e52acca376eb24eed70e8576949399) which is because the constructor of `ByteToMessageDecoder` invokes [ensureNotSharable()](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerAdapter.html#ensureNotSharable--). Why is this and is it possible to create a shared decoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [`ByteToMessageDecoder`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html):

> Be aware that sub-classes of ByteToMessageDecoder MUST NOT annotated with @Sharable.

Decoders cannot be shared. To work around this, instantiate a new decoder.